# How to add a column with row number in front of my query results?

Tags: sql, sql-function

I am working with a database that contains invoice data about online music purchases. My team is only interested in invoices sent to customers located in the city of London. I want to sort the invoices by order total in ascending order. The order totals are listed in the total column.

I wrote the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    invoice
WHERE
    billing_city = "London"
ORDER BY 
    total ASC;
```

This is my result:

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S2Wp.jpg)

Is there a way to add a column with row number in front of my query results table?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY total) rn
FROM invoice
WHERE billing_city = 'London'
ORDER BY total;
```